# Best way to attack a confusing SQL issue in inserting data into a TEMP table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working in SQL Server 2016. Confusing problem with SQL issue.  I have a TEMP table that contains unique rows. I have to insert 5 PRODUCTID values for each row each row based on another column value, AgentNo, in this temp table.  The PRODUCTID value, there are 5 of them, comes from another table but there is no relationship between the tables.  So my question is how do I insert a row for each ProductID into this temp table for each unique row that is currently in the temp table.

Here is a pic of the TEMP table that requires 5 rows for each:

[image]

Here is a pic of what I'm needing to come away with:

[image]

Here is my SQL code for both TEMP tables:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTarget') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTarget 
SELECT 0 as ProductID, 1 as [Status], a.AgentNo, u.UserID, u.[Password], 'N' as AdminID, tel.LocationSysID --, tel.OwnerID, tel.LocationName, a.OwnerSysID, a.AgentName
INTO #tempTarget
FROM dbo.TEST_EvalLocations tel
INNER JOIN dbo.AGT_Agent a
ON tel.LocationName = a.AgentName
INNER JOIN dbo.IW_User u
ON a.AgentNo = u.UserID
WHERE tel.OwnerID = 13313
AND tel.LocationSysID <> 15434;

SELECT * FROM #tempTarget WHERE LocationSysID NOT IN (15425, 15434);

GO

-- Create source table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempSource') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempSource
SELECT DISTINCT lpr.ProductID 
INTO #tempSource
FROM dbo.Eval_LocationProductRelationship lpr
WHERE lpr.ProductID IN (16, 15, 13, 14, 12) --BETWEEN 15435 AND 15595
```

Sorry I could not get this into a DDL file as these are TEMP tabless.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you might be looking for a cross-join against a rowset containing the 5 product ids.  With the caveat that I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to POPULATE the first TEMP table with the PRODUCT ID from another TEMP table.  I have 5 PRODUCTID values from the 2nd TEMP table.  And I need to create a row for each of the PRODUCT ID values for each unique record in the 1st TEMP table.  Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a job for cross-join

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll try it.

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

***CROSS JOIN*** will be the best solution for your case.

If you only want 5 rows for each data in First table means, simply use the below `cross join` query.

```
SELECT B.ProductID,
    A.[Status],
    A.AgentNo,
    A.UserID,
    A.[Password] AS Value,
    A.AdminID,
    A.LocationSysID 
FROM #tempTarget A
CROSS JOIN tempSource B
```

If you want additional row with `0`, then you have to insert a `0` into your second temp table and use the same query.

```
INSERT INTO #tempSource SELECT 0
```

Comment: Thanks DineshDB.  @Grax32 was able to provide the answer. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly following is the scenario, 
One Temp table has all the content.

```
select * from #withoutProducts
```

[image: table with all content]

product table

```
select * from #products
```

[image: Product table]

Then following is the query your are looking for

```
select a.ProductID,[Status],AgentNo,UserID,[value] 
from #products a  cross join  #withoutProducts b 
order by AgentNO,a.productID
```

[image]